# Multiple Schedulers or Multiple Job Triggers

Tags: c#, quartz.net, job-scheduling

I am using Quartz.net for my job scheduling.
I have different databases for my application and each needs to be considered for job processing.

I have two questions:

1. Can I use same scheduler for all my databases with different job triggers or one scheduler for each database? This is because the trigger time varies from database to database.
2. What are the advantages of one over the other? Which approach is best suited for my problem?

Comment: What do you mean by "trigger time varies from database to database"?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know quartz.net but I suppose this is the same as the java version.

As a scheduler instance can be bound to only one datasource, there is probably no way to achieve that. You'll need one instance per database.

The only way I can imagine is that you develop a new "connector" that merges the data from all the databases, but (much more difficult) it must also be able to save the data to the appropriated database...

Maybe you should create a Facade object that manages the list of Scheduler instances and exposes only this object to your application.

HIH